# Error while updating Database with mssql_query

Tags: sql-server, quoted-identifier, ansi-nulls

I'm using `mssql_query` to connect to an existing **SQL Server 2008 Database**.

`SELECT` querys are ok, but when I run `UPDATE` querys like the following:

```
mssql_query("UPDATE TABLENAME SET fieldname = 1 WHERE Pk = '".$pk."'");
```

I get this error:

> UPDATE failed because the following SET options have incorrect
>   settings: 'ANSI_NULLS, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL,
>   ANSI_WARNINGS, ANSI_PADDING'. Verify that SET options are correct for
>   use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or
>   filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type
>   methods and/or spatial index operations. (severity 16)

Here is my connection code to Database:

```
$server = 'SRVSQL';

// Connect to MSSQL
$link = mssql_connect($server, 'xx', 'xxxxxx');

if (!$link) {
    die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');
}

$conn = mssql_select_db('xxxxxxx',$link);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to explicitly change the settings by turning the settings on. You can do so by issuing the following query prior to the UPDATE statement:

```
SET 
  ANSI_NULLS, 
  QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, 
  CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, 
  ANSI_WARNINGS, 
  ANSI_PADDING 
ON;
```

Should there be additional settings yielding errors, those might have to be changed as well.

See also: [ANSWER: UPDATE failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_NULLS, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'](http://www.julian-kuiters.id.au/article.php/set-options-have-incorrect-settings)